# netty.io delivering static web content

Tags: java, html, http, webserver, netty

I was wondering if there is a way to deliver static web content (esentially css, js and html) using a netty.io instance.

I need this together with a web socket server and I would like to have a unique infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure... Just encode it in a FullHttpResponse and write it back. It's all just bytes..